# how to use global filter in filter datatable

Tags: jsf

How to use globalFilter in filter datatable.I'm using filterBy in all columns but here column based filter only working I want global filter to get records based on search word......

```
    <p:dataTable value="#{dataTableBean.usermodel}" var="datadto" paginator="true" rows="10"
                paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                rowsPerPageTemplate="2,5,10,15" widgetVar="dataTable" filteredValue="#{dataTableBean.userlist}">


    <f:facet name="header">  
        <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('dataTable').filter()" style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>  
    </f:facet>  

      <p:column headerText="CompanyId" filterBy="#{datadto.companyId}" filterStyle="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{datadto.companyId}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="CompanyName" filterBy="#{datadto.companyName}" filterStyle="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{datadto.companyName}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="CompanyDomain" filterBy="#{datadto.companyDomain}" filterStyle="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{datadto.companyDomain}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="TotalEmployees" filterBy="#{datadto.totalEmployees}" filterStyle="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{datadto.totalEmployees}"/>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="CompanyId" filterBy="#{datadto.salaryDetails}" filterStyle="display:none">
            <h:outputText value="#{datadto.salaryDetails}"/>
        </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
```

Comment: You need to stablish an `id` for your `dataTable` tied to what you specify in `PF('dataTable').filter()`. In this case `id="dataTable"` should work.

Comment: Global filter is based on widgetVar value or datatable id.

Comment: Then which problem do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<f:facet name="header">  
        <p:outputPanel>  
            <h:outputText value="Search all fields:" />  
            <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="dataTable.filter()" style="width:150px" />  
        </p:outputPanel>  
</f:facet>
```